# Windows Communication Foundation - from which version of .NET Framework?

Tags: wcf

What is "the oldest" version of .NET Framework that supports WCF technology?

In other words:

In which version of .NET Framework WCF first appeared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET 3.0 is when WCF was introduced:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation